# Organizing classes in C#

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Whats are some best practices for where/how you should have classes organized in a such way that its easy for the developer to use without any difficulty, I am creating a framework in C# static class library to provide bunch of functionality for a specific domain.

here is my design.

I have created a static class:

```
public static class Pages
{
   //static prop to get access HomePage class
   public static HomePage HomePage
   {
       get {
              var _home = new HomePage();
              return _home;
           }
   }
   //static prop to get access Employee class
   public static Employee EmployeePage
   {
       get {
              var _employeePage = new Employee();
              return _employeePage;
           }
   }
   //static prop to get access Employer class
   public static Employer EmployerPage
   {
       get {
              var _employerPage = new Employer();
              return _employerPage;
           }
   }

}
```

I have created separate classes (non static) for HomePage, Employee, Employer
for an example:

```
//Implementation class 
public class Employee
{    
    public bool Status()
    {
        return true;
    }

.... more code.....
```

}

Here is the important question:

user should be able to acess something like this.

```
bool _status = Page.Employee.Status();

or

Page.HomePage.SomeMethod();
```

am I going on the right direction?

**Concern:** The only concern I have with the above approach is that, `Pages` class.... I will be adding more classes and I will end-up having instantiation classes in the `Page` class is this okay to do?

or any other better approach?

Comment: is `EmployerPage` is derived from `Employer`?

Comment: so how do you returnn `EmployerPage` object type from the property of type `Employer` ? It would not compile at all.

Comment: Tigran: I just throw an example to get an idea but my core question is how should i approach if i am looking to have something like this: `Page.HomePage.<some_method_name>` if you have better idea let me know and this is just a beginning of my project :)

Comment: I doubt anybody will be able to help with your design, as your example doesn't fit with any design or correct use of C# that I've ever seen.  It might be clearer if you edit this post with details of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

No, I would definitely *not* do that. It's odd to have a static property which is *just* syntactic sugar (or in this case misdirection) for a constructor call. If you actually wanted to hide the implementation class, it would make a bit more sense (although I'd make those static properties methods instead) but I don't see the benefit here.

Additionally, `Status` sounds like it ought to be a *property*, not a method. Oh, and an `Employee` doesn't sound like a `Page` to me - it sounds like the employee data itself. Make your type names describe what they represent. So you should have something like:

```
bool status = new EmployeePage().Status;
```

Comment: Jon, thanks, its just an example I wanted to pass but I do understand i should have more meaningful name but my core question is how should i approach if i am looking to have something like this: `Page.HomePage.<some_method_name>`

Comment: @AbuHamzah: You should first ask yourself *why* you're looking to subvert normal C# coding. You should *either* just create the page directly, or you should have the page given to you as a dependency. I see no benefit in the approach you've suggested here - you're adding fluff with no benefit.

Comment: I hear you clearly Jon! my question is all about the best practice and if you think its fluff how would you come-up with the design and i would like to see

Answer (score 0):

The Pages class feels much more like a namespace than a class. And the properties you sketched there *create* a page rather than getting something. That doesn't feel right. What you have build seems much more to become a factory. Do you want a factory or what is the purpose of accumulating these properties in the Pages class?

Since you're very vague on what you want to achieve the answer is too. But it immediately feels strange to have so many static in one place, except for constants maybe.

Comment: the reason I have `prop` in the `Pages` class is to get the access to other classes without instantiate the class- well that's the whole purpose of my class

Comment: I take that as a hint to decouple the implementation from the interface. Maybe you should take a look at how interfaces and classes work in C#. Thats already much ground to cover. But as a follow up you could investigate into factory pattern.

Comment: Never mind, You are on different page then what i am trying to do.